# Using Babel/Webpack only for transpilling/polyfilling

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a very old javascript code base and I do not want to use the modern way of compiling all of the javascript files into one using standard webpack because it is not possible due to the way the website code is written.

But I want to write new scripts using modern Javascript (e.g. Promises and Fetch) but still be able to support old browsers like IE11.

I have configured webpack and babel so it gets multiple entry javascript files and for each of them it does the classic transpiling/polyfilling using `@babel/preset-env` and `corejs`.

This works and polyfills every script based on the babel target config but it creates one issue. It encapsulates global variables/functions in the script so they are not accessible from other scripts which reference them (yes old javascript). Is there a way to disable this structural modifications?

Also I know I could use only Babel without Webpack for this but the problem is when I try to polyfill e.g. Fetch I have to use https://github.com/github/fetch which cannot be just used with Babel afaik.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://death-to-ie11.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think inevitably your refactorings are modernizing the code, and if you are not careful, one day you can end up bundling everything with webpack;)

The set up you describe, I achieved with with:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    messages: "./src/messages",
    "hello-world": "./src/hello-world",
  },
  output: {
    library: {
      type: "global",
    },
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```

every **export** from each file is put directly on `window` - if you load files in the right order, you can have invisible dependencies maintained across the codebase.

To this setup, you can add babel loader with presets as you stated in your question. Besides, you can tart doing the explicit imports across different files - even if function X is available on global scope, you can migrate some places to import/require it explicitly.

If you want to play with my code yourself, you can find it here:
https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-legacy/

and here is the example in action:
https://marcin-wosinek.github.io/webpack-legacy/

Comment: thank you. this sadly doesnt work as I would wish it would since it expects exports in the javascript file which is not really possible due to the amount of code in question. yes i know, it needs to be refactored, this is hopefully a temporary solution